I have .3081 BTC & cost basis of 97.530 & account value of $30,000. I need the formula to 'predict' what I will have when BTC hits $120,000 etc
Will you please help me? I have .3081 BTC and cost basis of 97.530 and account value of $30,000. I need the formula to 'predict' what I will have when BTC hits $110,000, $115,000 , $120,000 etc.




At this time
You have or will have




Now
0.3081 BTC


When BTC hits $110,000
0.3081 BTC


When BTC hits $115,000
0.3081 BTC


When BTC hits $120,000
0.3081 BTC



If you want the answer in some arbitrary fiat currency, apply the appropriate exchange rate



At this time
You have or will have the equivalent of




Now
0.3081 x 97,740 USD


When BTC hits $110,000
0.3081 x 110,000 USD


When BTC hits $115,000
0.3081 x 115,000 USD


When BTC hits $120,000
0.3081 x 120,000 USD



If you want to calculate capital gains to calculate your liability for capital gains tax or similar purposes, subtract your cost basis expressed in your reporting currency. I'm no tax expert but I believe in most jurisdictions a capital gain is only realised when the asset is sold. In the case of cash, I think that would normally be when the cash is converted to another currency or used to purchase something. But you should ask a tax adviser about that.

The formula is number of BTC * price.
